# VHDL: Multiple for loop serial execution

Tags: arrays, sorting, for-loop, integer, vhdl

I might be new to synthesizing loops. I am trying to create a counting sort in VHDL which takes arbitary length(say N) of integer array as input for sorting.
The code for design heavily relies on for loop. The looping logic seems to be parallel within a process or may be across processes. So I put all of the for loop in one process. But with that, the loops seem to execute in parallel independently. Which defeats the purpose as one loop should follow the other.

I have used counting sort algorithm from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

I am unable to get the logic working as mentioned in the algorithm.
**Q1**: How does the for loop execute within a process. Does all the for loop execute in parallel.
**Q2**:Is there an alternate way of implementing this for loop logic in VHDL, so that it executes serially?
**Q3**:Are there limitations for synthesizing for loops?

Design code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package sorting_pkg is
  type intarray is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use work.sorting_pkg.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Sorting is
    generic (
      N : integer );
    port( 
        --clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        inStream : in intarray(0 to N-1);
        outStream : out intarray(0 to N-1);
        BoutArray: out intarray(0 to 16);
        CoutArray: out intarray(0 to 16)
    );
end entity;

architecture behavior of Sorting is
    signal BArray: intarray(0 to 16) := (others => "00000000");
    signal CArray: intarray(0 to 16) := (others => "00000000");
    signal DArray: intarray(0 to 16) := (others => "00000000");
    --signal Aindex1,Aindex2,Cindex,k: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    --signal Aindex1,Aindex2,Cindex,k : natural range 0 to 16; 
begin
process
    begin 
    if(rst = '1') then
        outStream <=(others => "00000000");
    else
       Bloop: for i in 0 to N-1 loop
        BArray(to_integer(unsigned(inStream(i)))) <=BArray(to_integer(unsigned(inStream(i)))) + 1;
        end loop;
        CArray(0) <= BArray(0);
       Cloop: for j in 1 to 16 loop 
        CArray(j) <= BArray(j) + CArray(j - 1);
        end loop;
       Coutloop:for l in 0 to N-1 loop

        DArray(to_integer(unsigned(inStream(l)))) <= CArray(to_integer(unsigned(inStream(l)))) - 1;
        end loop;
        outloop:for m in 0 to N-1 loop
     outStream(to_integer(unsigned(DArray(to_integer(unsigned(inStream(m))))))) <= inStream(m); 
        end loop;
        BoutArray <= BArray;
        CoutArray <= DArray;
     end if;
     wait;


  end process;--end proc
end architecture;
```

Testbench code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work; 
use work.sorting_pkg.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity tb_camera is
--  Port ( );
end tb_camera;

architecture Behavioral of tb_camera is

component Sorting
    generic (
      N : integer := 10);
    PORT
        (--clk: in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        inStream : in intarray(0 to 9);
        outStream : out intarray(0 to 9);
        BoutArray: out intarray(0 to 16);
        CoutArray: out intarray(0 to 16)
                );
end component;

signal A : intarray(0 to 9);
signal D : intarray(0 to 9);
signal rst_tb       : std_logic;
-- signal clk_tb       : std_logic;
signal BoutArray       : intarray(0 to 16);
signal CoutArray       : intarray(0 to 16);
--constant clk_period : time :=500ns;

begin
    uut:Sorting port map (inStream => A, outStream => D, rst => rst_tb,
                           BoutArray => BoutArray, CoutArray=> CoutArray );


    sim_tb:process
        begin
            wait for 100ns;
            rst_tb<='1';
            wait for 100ns;
            rst_tb<='0';

            --wait for 50ns;
            A(0 to 9) <= (0 => x"07",
                          1 => x"09",
                          2 => x"06",
                          3 => x"02",
                          4 => x"05",
                          5 => x"00",
                          6 => x"08",
                          7 => x"01",
                          8 => x"03",
                          9 => x"04");
            wait;
            end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Are you trying to create synthesisable code? If not the soultion might be as simple as using variables instead of signals. Signals only change there value after the whole processes finishes executing. Variables change immediately giving you the serial/sequential flow that you want.

Comment: Need synthesizable code

Comment: Where is the clock signal?